# Integrate elastic search with Logrus (golang logging)

Tags: go, elasticsearch, logging, error-logging, logrus

I am using `logrus` to do all the logging my golang application. However, I also want to integrate this with Elastic Search such that all the logs are also flushed to elastic search when I create a logrus log entry. Currently all logs are created in a file as shown in the snippet below. How could I integrate with elastic search?

```
type LoggerConfig struct {
    Filename string `validate:regexp=.log$`
    AppName  string `validate:regexp=^[a-zA-Z]$`
}  

type AppLogger struct {
    Err    error
    Logger logrus.Entry
}

func Logger(loggerConfig LoggerConfig) AppLogger {
    response := new(AppLogger)
    // validate the schema of the logger_config
    if errs := validator.Validate(loggerConfig); errs != nil {
        response.Err = errs
        // this sets up the error on the the response struct
    }

    logrus.SetFormatter(&logrus.JSONFormatter{})
    f, err := os.OpenFile(loggerConfig.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        response.Err = err
    }
    multipleWriter := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
    logrus.SetOutput(multipleWriter)

    contextLogger := logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "app": loggerConfig.AppName,
    })


    //logrus.AddHook(hook)
    response.Logger = *contextLogger

    //response.Logger.Info("adele")
    return *response

}
```

I had tried `elogrus` which adds a hook but I am not sure how to use it. Here is the method which attempts to create elastic search client. How could I integrate this with logrus instance?

```
func prepareElasticSearchClient() *elastic.Client {
    indexName := "my-server"

    client, _ := elastic.NewClientFromConfig(&config.Config{
        URL:      os.Getenv("ELASTIC_SEARCH_URL_LOGS") + ":" + os.Getenv("ELASTIC_SEARCH_PORT_LOGS"),
        Index:    indexName,
        Username: os.Getenv("ELASTIC_SEARCH_USERNAME_LOGS"),
        Password: os.Getenv("ELASTIC_SEARCH_PASSWORD_LOGS"),
    })

    return client
}
```

Earlier I have used modules like `Winston` where it was super easy to setup elastic search logging but somehow, I find little documentation with golang on how to integrate Golang logging with elastic search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `elogrus` you first create Elastic client and pass it to `elogrus` hook when creating it with `elogrus.NewAsyncElasticHook()`. Hook just wraps sending message to Elastic. Then you add this hook to `logrus` `log`. Every time you log message using `log` it will fire your hook and send message (if log level filter passes) to Elastic.

```golang
log := logrus.New()
client, err := elastic.NewClient(elastic.SetURL("http://localhost:9200"))
// ... handle err
hook, err := elogrus.NewAsyncElasticHook(client, "localhost", logrus.DebugLevel, "testlog")
// ... handle err
log.Hooks.Add(hook)
```

Signature of `NewAsyncElasticHook` is `(client *elastic.Client, host string, level logrus.Level, index string)` where:

- `client` is pointer to `Elastic.Client` you obtained before using `elastic`
- `host` is string that denotes from which host you are sending the log trace (it's a string - hostname of host where program that logs is running)
- `level` is the maximum logrus log level you want messages to be sent (e.g. if you want to see DEBUG messages locally but only send only ERROR and below to Elastic)
- `index` is name of Elastic Search index you want to add messages from `log` to

From here you can use `log` normally as you would do with `logrus` and all messages will get passed to Elastic.

Another part of issue was a bit more tricky and rooted in (not only) Golang `elastic` client node sniffing behavior. We debugged it in chat and summary was posted as my answer to OP's another question regarding that: [Cannot connect to elastic search : no active connection found: no Elasticsearch node available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455272/cannot-connect-to-elastic-search-no-active-connection-found-no-elasticsearch)

Comment: What does `localhost` and `testlog` mean in the call to `NewAsyncElasticHook`? Could you please describe this?

Comment: If I call `prepareElasticSearchClient` method as given in my question, it just gives an error `no active connection found: no Elasticsearch node available`. Do. not understand why this happens.

Comment: @Amanda updated my answer with details to answer `"localhost"` and `"testlog"` questions. Regarding your `prepareElasticSearchClient` are your environment variables set properly, can your host reach Elastic server?

Comment: @Amanda also, do you have matching version of Elastic and `elogrus` ? See https://github.com/sohlich/elogrus

Comment: My elastic search version number is `7.6.2` and my elogrus package version is `gopkg.in/sohlich/elogrus.v7`

Comment: The env variables are set properly. I even tried by replacing env variables with hard coded strings. For example the URL is `http://ip:port` and I can reach via browser and it is up and running. What could be the issue?

Comment: @Amanda Can you try, instead of populating `Config` directly doing something like `config, err := config.Parse("http://user:pwd@host:port/index")` with hardcoded values and then pass config to `elastic.NewClientFromConfig()`? I never used `Config` directly like you do so maybe issue is somewhere in its initialization.

Comment: I also tried the way you mentioned (not using config) but still did not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455272/cannot-connect-to-elastic-search-no-active-connection-found-no-elasticsearch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212605/discussion-between-blami-and-amanda).